# Link Graph to Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

i'm stucked again. Is there any way to "connect" a graph from a form to a MYSQL database? I made the connections(forms-> database). I want that graph to automaticaly loads the columns, and the values from my database . Thanks a lot !

Comment: This a the rare case, where even after reading your question several times, I don't have the __faintest__ idea what you want to do..

Comment: Well, i want to make a graph to show how many columns and values are in my database and how much overloaded is my database ....

Comment: this is my task : "The application allows to show a graphic which describes the relations between the tables, and the application   allows to create an another graphic which describes the level of how many values are in  tables from the DB** ANY DATABASE, the chart needs to update dinamicaly for any table. If i'll change the collumn name, the charts needs to know the new Column name ! ) Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I assume you want to show a `Chart`?

It is easy to use, just drop it on the form, define its series and load points.

Some or all of the Information you are looking for is in the metatables of each DBMS; in MYSQL these are in the various `information_schema` tables. Below is an example that loads all table names and the count of their columns into a chart named `ch_tables`, which contains one series called `columns`. It assumes you have an open `Connection`called `DBC`and a `Database` provided in the parameter.

```
 public void loadChart(string schema)
 {
   try
   {   
     string allTables =
           " SELECT table_name, count(COLUMN_NAME) " 
         + " FROM information_schema.COLUMNS " 
         + " where table_schema = '" + schema + "' group by table_name" ;

     MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(allTables, DBC);
     MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

     ch_tables.Series["columns"].Points.Clear();
     while (rdr.Read()) 
     {
         ch_tables.Series["columns"].Points.AddXY(rdr[0], rdr[1]);
     }
     rdr.Close();
   } 

   catch (MySqlException ex)  { /* error handling */ }
 }
```

I hope this gives you a start to expand it and to create other charts.

The `information_schema` tables contain a lot of intersting stuff; you can find the number of rows as `TABLE_ROWS` in `information_schema.TABLES`.

When asking a question it is always a good idea to give both us and yourself as much details as possible. Creating a dummy chart in Excel would have been a good idea to show just what you mean..

**EDIT** : I accidentally hard coded the schema name, even though the function was prepared to read of a dynamically choosen database..

Comment: the points is i want to dinamicaly load chart to any Database i connect.

Comment: if you mean other databases than MYSQL you will have to check out their respective meta tables; they all have them but not all are named and structured alike. Also see my edit!

Comment: this is my task : "The application allows to show a graphic which describes the relations between the tables, and the application allows to create an another graphic which describes the level of how many values are in tables from the DB** ANY DATABASE, the chart needs to update dinamicaly for any table. If i'll change the collumn name, the charts needs to know the new Column name ! ) Any help? Thanks

Comment: I tried your code, it works only for how many columns are in each table. But i need how many Rows are in each table. If i write  SELECT table_name, count(TABLE_ROWS) " + " FROM information_schema.TABLES " in chart, it only display 1 ...and i have a lot of rows...

Comment: You can select table_rows directly. Here is a SQL with hard coded schema name: SELECT information_schema.COLUMNS.table_name, count(COLUMN_NAME), 
 table_rows FROM information_schema.COLUMNS, information_schema.TABLES 
where information_schema.COLUMNS.table_schema = 'test' 
and information_schema.COLUMNS.table_name = information_schema.TABLES.table_name
group by information_schema.COLUMNS.table_name;

Comment: Can you please edit my code ? I repeat, i hope i am understood: I want to count All Rows From each table from database.                 string Tabele =
                      " SELECT table_name, count(*) "
                    + " FROM information_schema.TABLES "
                    + " where table_schema = '" + Form1._myConnection.Database + "' group by table_name";

Comment: Simply replace `count(*)` by `table_rows` like in the previous comment!

Comment: string Tabele = " SELECT table_name, sum(table_rows) " + " FROM information_schema.TABLES " + " where table_schema = '" + Form1._myConnection.Database + "' group by table_name"; if i put with sum, it will sum only from 1 table ######## and if i try with Count(table_rows) there's no result. My chart displays only 1 row per table

Comment: i think i'll need a for to count rows from all tables.

Comment: No. The column  `information_schema.TABLES.table_rows` contains the row count. The SQL I gave you displays table names, column count and row count. Note that you can't simply _chart_ the column count and the row count together since they are so different. One would need to be scaled.

Comment: can u rewrite the query to select only the rows? (adapted to my code):  " SELECT table_name, count(table_rows) " + " FROM information_schema.TABLES " + " where table_schema = '" + Form1._myConnection.Database + "' group by table_name";